# Spring Boot + Java modules = Unsupported class file major version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have weird problem that `mvn clean test` fails only when I try to add `module-info.java` to my project using Spring Boot.
Project structure is very simple

```
    │   pom.xml
    │
    ├───.idea
    │       .gitignore
    │       compiler.xml
    │       encodings.xml
    │       jarRepositories.xml
    │       misc.xml
    │       workspace.xml
    │
    └───src
        ├───main
        │   ├───java
        │   │   │   module-info.java
        │   │   │
        │   │   └───com
        │   │       └───test
        │   └───resources
        └───test
            ├───java
            │   └───com
            │       └───test
            │               SomeTest.java
            │
            └───resources
```

`SomeTest.java` is very simple

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class SomeTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        var isTrue = true;
        Assertions.assertTrue(isTrue);
    }
}
```

`module-info.java` also:

```
open module com.test {
}
```

`pom.xml` file is taken from sprint initalizr

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And now the weird thing is that when `module-info.java` file is present then `mvn clean test` fails
[image: Unsupported class file major version 61]

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project SampleTest: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test failed: Unsupported class file major version 61 -> [Help 1]
```

but when I delete `module-info.java` then everything goes without error. Any ideas how can I achieve java modules with spring boot? :)

Comment: What does `mvn --version` tell you? Are you running on plain command line?

Comment: Please do not use images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/296328

Comment: @khmarbaise maven version is 3.8.3
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.3 (...)
Maven home: X:\apache-maven-3.8.3
Java version: 17, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: X:\Java\jdk-17
Default locale: pl_PL, platform encoding: Cp1250
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: Also added the error as code for to be better indexed :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to overwrite the used maven-surefire-plugin version because the version defined by spring boot parent is too old.

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
...
```

Comment: That does the trick! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

For the problem after migration to reactive webflux with spring-boot 3, the`blockhound-junit-platform.version` version must be updated.
For Spring-boot 3.2, I used:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>blockhound-junit-platform</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8.RELEASE</version> <!-- It was 1.0.4.RELEASE -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```